# Javascript/JQuery for animated scrolling from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've got animated scrolling from [here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links/). This works well for same page, when in index.html:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#section1">Natural Beauty</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Beginings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Earth's Purity</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4">Bottling Goodness</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section5">Drink to Health</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section6">Minerals</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

here's the js i've used from the refference above:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'')
    && this.hash.replace(/index.html#/,'') ) {
  var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
      if ($target) {
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
        // JQUERY CLICK FUNCTION REMOVE AND ADD CLASS "ACTIVE" + SCROLL TO THE #DIV
          $(this).click(function() {
            $("#nav li a").removeClass("active");
            $("#nav2 li a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1200);
            return false;
          });
       }
    }
  });
});
```

test the code above and when you click one of your gnav, it'll jump to your section, smooth transition and the header still print/show 'just' the 'index.html' (the #section will not print/shown).
Now, how can I make this work's if I tried to acces it from different page. I want to acces it from index2.html, so when the gnav look like these:

```
<ul id="nav2">
    <li><a href="index.html#section1">•Natural Beauty</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#section2">•Beginings</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#section3">•Earth's Purity</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#section4">•Bottling Goodness</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#section5">•Drink to Health</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#section6">•Minerals</a></li>
</ul>
```

It do jump to the actual page, but the header change to index.html#section(1/2/..). How can I make the gnav jump to actual section and the header still print the index.html and without print/shown the #section. Please ask me if my question didn't clear. Thanks for your help.
ps: sorry I don't know how to paste it in fiddle since the fiddle can't show whats in the header. Again, thanks for your help

Comment: can you provide a fiddle of the problem??

Comment: So are you using the jQuery smooth scrolling plugin or did you implement the code in the example? If you're using the code post what it looks like in your application.

Comment: I've edited my question and add js that i've used

Comment: Have you consider using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead? You can use it with [normal scroll](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html) if you want, and you can use `recordHistory:true` if you prefer.

Comment: yep, I already done it with fullPage.js, works well. Unfortunately, my client doesn't like that and want to stick with this-parrallax version -_-

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of code.

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
   if(window.location.hash != ""){
       $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top},'slow');
   }
})
```

Comment: nope. It jump to the section page, but the header still print/shown the #section.so the result is: index.html#section

Comment: Ok so you want to remove the #section ?

Comment: not the #section area, just the string after the hash(#) in the header

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate your history state to remove the url hash (#) section. In your document ready try to add this line

```
history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
```